# Adding Task's to User's Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

I would like to have my program, Winforms currently, be able to add Task's to a User's Outlook (2010) Task List.  I have figured out how to do that from within an Outlook Addin, [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/02/23/how-to-create-a-new-recurrent-task-item/), but not from my Desktop app.  Furthermore, can I assign a Task to someone other than the current user through code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) (EWS) for interacting with other users' tasks from your desktop App. You can [create Task items via EWS for other users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563029%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) if you have delegate access to their mailbox.